# Unable to Rename form field in PDF using iText Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to rename the existing field with new name using iText library.
But below code is not helping out.

```
public static void testRenameFields() throws Exception{
    String SRC = "C:\\Citi\\esign\\pdfs\\SS_Application_fields.pdf";
    String DEST = "C:\\Citi\\esign\\pdfs\\abc.pdf";
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
   PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
   AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
   System.out.println("FieldType : "+form.getFieldType("signers[0].firstName"));
   form.renameField("signers[0].firstName", "Firstname");
   System.out.println("FieldType : "+form.getFieldType("Firstname"));
   stamper.close();
   reader.close();

}
```

Output of this snippet is 
`FieldType : 4
FieldType : 0`

Even i have renamed the field, it is giving me output for existing field. and new name is not attached to that field.

NOTE:   FieldType 0 - Field Doesnt exist
          FieldType 4 - Text type Field

Anyone knows any alternative way to rename the field in PDF using iText.

Please advice!!

Comment: I just got the cause, why it wasn't working for me. I have "." (dot) in my field name and it seems itext's renameField () method doesn't support field name with "." (dot). I changed dot to "_" and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You try to rename "signers[0].firstName" to "Firstname". This is not possible using `AcroFields.renameField`, cf. its JavaDoc documentation:

```
/**
 * Renames a field. Only the last part of the name can be renamed. For example,
 * if the original field is "ab.cd.ef" only the "ef" part can be renamed.
 *
 * @param oldName the old field name
 * @param newName the new field name
 * @return <CODE>true</CODE> if the renaming was successful, <CODE>false</CODE>
 * otherwise
 */
public boolean renameField(String oldName, String newName)
```

Thus, you could rename "signers[0].firstName" to "signers[0].reallyFirstName" but everything up to the final '.' needs to remain unchanged.

---

If you wonder about the reason for this restriction: fields actually are not necessarily arranged as a flat list but instead as a tree, and the name of a field is the concatenation of the tree node names with periods as separators in-between. Trying to change the field name anywhere before the final dot could imply having to change the tree structure but the method in question was implemented for simply renaming only.

Answer (score 1):

Just read after closing stamper and reader. Below is the working code example

public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {

```
    String src = "C:\\Workspace\\pdf1\\2053-C.pdf";
    String dest= "C:\\Workspace\\pdf1\\_renamed_2053-C.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.renameField("cpa_t1", "renamed_cpa_t1");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    reader = new PdfReader(dest);
    form = reader.getAcroFields();
    Map<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = form.getFields();

    for (String name : fields.keySet()) {

        if (name.equals("renamed_cpa_t1")) {
            System.out.println("Renamed :: " + name);
        }
    }

   System.out.println("FieldType : " + form.getFieldType("renamed_cpa_t1"));
}
```